# Using page anchors in <Select> dropdown list in html

Tags: html, select

I have a static HTML page that contains a lot of tables. I would like to use the html tag `<select>` to create a simple dropdown menu which jumps to a specific table further down the page.

What command sets the user selection to jump down the page and what anchor code is required to give that selection a target.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You'll need JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you just need to use JavaScript to make it so when you click/change value on the select box it takes you to the link specified in the value of that select option.

```
<select name="dropdpown" size="1" id="select-anchor">
    <option value="#link">foo</option>
    <option value="#link">bar</option>
</select>
```

And using jQuery library for the JavaScript functionality simplifies things (and will other JS related features of your web project)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-anchor').change( function () {
        var targetPosition = $($(this).val()).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetPosition}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgzwE/1/) of it in action.

Comment: What would the target down page look like?

Comment: `<table id="#link"></table>` or `<a id="#link"></a>` etc

Comment: I cut and pasted your script as above into the JS tag about body and used an option value="#x" then down page put <a id="#x"> </a>

Comment: Have you included jQuery: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: <script type="menu/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="menu/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-anchor').change( function () {
        var targetPosition = $($(this).val()).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetPosition}, 'slow');
    });
});
</script>
IS THIS CORRECT?

Comment: Well look at the jsFiddle I linked and read the source of the Output frame. Your comment has been truncated.

Comment: @Lupine99 the `id` should ***NOT*** contain the hash character (`#`). So: `<div id='x'>` will be the target of `<option value='#x'>X target</option>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without JavaScript. ***Nor you should***.

I, as a user, expect to select a value from a dropdown list. Select one item between others. Not act as navigation.

One can argue that it's OK if done for a mobile browser, but that's still bad UX.

Comment: It's a neat way of providing a method of jumping to one of a large list of options on a long page, without having to display every link option. One argument might be that perhaps a `ul li` solution is neater, however.

Comment: I think there are situations when this is preferable to using an accordion, this being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can go to a link on select:

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" >                            
    <option value="search.php?perpage=10">10</option>
    <option value="search.php?perpage=20">20</option>
    <option value="search.php?perpage=50">50</option>
    <option value="search.php?perpage=100">100</option>
</select>
```