# drop down list of hyperlinks

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc application JSP page, I am trying to simplify the layout by giving the user a drop down list from which to select a desired action.  The items in the drop down list would each correspond with a different url for other JSPs to which the user would be directed.  This would make the user interface a lot cleaner than having a separate button for each possible URL.  How do I set this up in code?

Here is the jsp code in Spring Expression Language for creating the drop down list that I have so far:

```
<form:select path="AddLink" cssClass="textArea">
    <option value="Select" label=" - Select - " ></option>
    <form:options items="${AddLinks}"/>
</form:select>
```

Here are the methods in the controller for populating the drop down list and then for handling its selection that I have so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/encounters", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam("encounterID") String encounterId, Encounter encounter, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    int encountId = Integer.parseInt(encounterId);
    Encounter sel_encounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(encountId);//I added this
    HashMap<String,String> AddLinks = new HashMap<String,String>();
    AddLinks.put("New this","/thislink");
    AddLinks.put("New that","/thatlink");
    AddLinks.put("New other thing","/otherlink");
    model.put("sel_encounter",sel_encounter);
    ((Model) model).addAttribute("AddLinks", AddLinks);
    return "encounters/encountersList";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/encounters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processFindForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, @ModelAttribute("AddLink") String addLink, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    int encountId = encounter.getId();
    System.out.println("............ addLink is:  "+addLink);
    return "/"+addLink;
}
```

This is causing the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/encounters/encountersList.jsp at line 116

113:                 <spring:url value="" var="medications_newUrl"></spring:url>
114:                 <a href="${fn:escapeXml(medications_newUrl)}" class="btn btn-info" >Add New Medication</a>
115:
116: <form:select path="AddLink" cssClass="textArea">
117:     <option value="Select" label=" - Select - " ></option>
118:     <form:options items="${AddLinks}"/>
119: </form:select>

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

root cause 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'AddLink' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:200)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.encounters.encountersList_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(encountersList_jsp.java:1396)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.encounters.encountersList_jsp._jspService(encountersList_jsp.java:405)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

For reference, here are the taglibs included at the top of the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="petclinic" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
```

**NOTE: I think the problem is from using `atModelAttribute` to pass a string into the controller method.**  I think the error means that spring is looking for an object AddLink when I just want to pass a string.  Does this help you see the solution?

---

### EDIT:

By changing all the `AddLink` references to `AddLinks`, I got the JSP to compile with a drop down list of the link choices, but selecting any of the choices has NO EFFECT.  The JSP does not redirect, and the `System.out.println()` in the `POST` controller method does not print anything out, indicating that the `POST` controller method has not been called.

Here is the only code that I changed:

```
// in the JSP
<form:select path="AddLinks" cssClass="textArea">
    <option value="Select" label=" - Select - " ></option>
    <form:options items="${AddLinks}"/>
</form:select>  

// in the controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/encounters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processFindForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, @ModelAttribute("AddLink") String AddLinks, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    int encountId = encounter.getId();
    System.out.println("............ addLink is:  "+AddLinks);
    return "/"+AddLinks;
}
```

The complete JSP can be found on a file sharing site [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/K4TS67ip6r30uVNVcmzg?b=6cvlhQgjSKinTnKAutgN).

Comment: Then why dont you try to use `onchange` event or may `onSelect` event .. ? When the user selects the option redirect to desired page .

Comment: @looser Thank you.  Can you show me how that would look in code?  I am still learning this.

Comment: your post & get methods are completely wrong..

Comment: @Rembo Can you suggest specific changes to make them work?

Comment: @CodeMed show complete form in jsp

Comment: @Rembo I uploaded the complete JSP to a file sharing site and put a link to it at the end of my original posting above.  Does this enable you to see how to fix the problem?

Comment: @CodeMed, k, will see

Comment: @CodeMed, add encounter bean as model object in GET method then in jsp use spring form tag by specifying modelAttribute, then you can navigate from server on form submission.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48426/discussion-between-rembo-and-codemed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

Modify your Encounter class to hold a value of selectedLink like:

```
public class Encounter {

    private String selectedLink;

    //getters and setters

}
```

then, in controller to add a AddLinks options as a modelAttribute do like this:

```
    public String getFindForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("enctr",new Encounter());
        return "AddLink";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processFindForm(@ModelAttribute("enctr")Encounter encounter){
        System.out.println(encounter.getSelectedLink());    

        return "AddLink";//"redirect:"+encounter.getSelectedLink();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("addLinkOptions")
    public Map loadLinkOptions(){
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> addLinks = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        addLinks.put("/thislink","New this");
        addLinks.put("/thatlink","New that");
        addLinks.put("/otherlink","New other thing");
        return addLinks;
    }
```

and in your jsp add a spring form:form tag to perform action.

```
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="enctr">
        SelectLink:
        <form:select path="selectedLink">
            <form:option value="NONE">--select--</form:option>
            <form:options items="${addLinkOptions}"/>
        </form:select>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar like @looser I would also argue you'd better off coding this on client side using javascript, but anyway here's the server side answer:

Firstly I think you forgot to `model.addAttribute("AddLinks", AddLinks)`. I can see you're creating a HashMap which never gets added to the model.

Secondly in `processFindForm` you can return the string "redirect:/blah" to give a HTTP 3xx redirect into `/blah` URI. The redirection URL is relative to your context path.

Read more about [spring view redirection here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying a server side solution.  I implemented your changes in code that I added in a revision to my original posting above.  I also added the stack trace which describes the error that is currently keeping the code from compiling.  Can you show me how to fix the code so that it works?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the spring `<form>` taglib :(

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  I just added the list of taglibs in the JSP to the end of my original posting above.  Those tagligs are at the top of the JSP, and they seem to include the `form` taglib.  If the `form` taglib is present, can you see what the problem is?

Comment: I think the problem is from using `atModelAttribute` to pass a string into the controller method.  I think the error means that spring is looking for an object AddLink when I just want to pass a string.  Does this help you see the solution?

Comment: Scrolling down to the bottom of your stack trace shows something obvious: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'AddLink' available as request attribute`. And looking at your edited controller method, I'm not sure what you're doing here: `Map<String, Object> model` `((Model) model).addAttribute("AddLinks", AddLinks);`, typically you just pass `Model model` as arg to be injected by spring

Comment: Eclipse required the cast to `Model` in `((Model) model).addAttribute("AddLinks",AddLinks)` because the argument in the controller method is of type `Map<String, Object> model` instead of `Model model` . Does this help you isolate the error?

Comment: As an experiment, I changed all the `AddLink` references to `AddLinks`, and got the results that I just posted in an edit to my original posting above.  Does this help you isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i am not familiar with Spring MVC but in your requirement

```
 onChange or onSelect event is enough

<form:select path="AddLink" cssClass="textArea" onChange='setAction()' >
<option value="Select" label=" - Select - " ></option>
<form:options items="${AddLinks}"/>
</form:select>

In javaScript

  <script type="text/javascript">

        function setAction()
        {
           var temp = document.getElementById("selectTagID"); 
           var action = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;//get Selected option key value
            document.form_name.action =action;//Send the action
             document.form_name.submit();//Submit the form

        }
  </script>
```

Where in your Otions list make those actions are available .. as keys for that selected options

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to think about my question.  But I did not put JavaScript in the question or in the tags.  I want a server side solution using spring mvc and java, to match all the rest of my code in my application.

Comment: Hmm I thought you said okay for the events I mentioned there .. Okay Now How do you want to send the action then ? When user selects the option or user will click some button after selecting the option in drop down ?

Comment: Look at the bottom of `processFindForm()` at the end of my original posting above.  See that it tries to redirect the user to the url specified by the chosen value of `addLink`.  It would be nice if the redirect occurred when the user clicked on the selected item in the drop down list.  At the moment the server says it cannot find a bean value for `addLink`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391978/using-page-anchors-in-select-dropdown-list-in-html I think in that case you can not do with out JAVASCRIPT